# How big a knife is required for eid qurban sacrifice?

Tags: fiqh, dhabihah

Are there any requirements in Islam for the size of the knife used for qurban? How big must be a knife for a sheep?

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. For further information about our site and its model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. As to your question I don't know of any specific claim about a size, but its important that the used knife is sharp enough so that one might be able to do the slaughtering with only one try!

Answer (score 1):

I asked this question to the imam of my mosque and he said that there are no specifications about the size of the knife. Although it is recommended the knife should be sharp enough so that the animal could be sacrificed easily without giving him/her much pain.

Answer (score 1):

There are no obligatory requirements regarding the knife or tool which is used for slaughtering. Anything which is able to cut the vessels (arteries, food-pipe and windpipe) and sheds blood is sufficient and will render the meat halal:

> ما أنهر الدم وذكر اسم الله عليه فكلوا ما لم يكن سنا أو ظفرا
>
> When Allah's name is mentioned you may eat what is killed by anything which causes the blood to flow except tooth and claw.
>
> <sup>— [Abu Dawud](https://sunnah.com/abudawud:2821),  [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:2507) etc.</sup>

However it is recommended that the knife should be sharp and generally one which will be a cause of ease for the animal:

> وإذا ذبحتم فأحسنوا الذبح وليحد أحدكم شفرته فليرح ذبيحته
>
> When you slaughter, slaughter in a good way. So every one of you should sharpen his knife, and let the slaughtered animal die comfortably.
>
> <sup>— [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim:1955a)</sup>

And in this regard a longer knife (equal or bigger than the size of the neck) is better since it cuts swiftly with less force and fewer strokes and hence lessens the suffering of the animal.